# List of letters, into a list of numbers

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I'm trying to find a simple way of converting a list of letters, into a list of numbers. Given each letter has a certain value - for example;

letters = [F, G, H, F, J, K]

Where F is 10, G is 20, H is 30, J is 40 and K is 50.

I made a semi-working program using if/elif/else and giving each letter a variable of the number, but I was just wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this, though without the uses of dictionaries.

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: You can define bunch of variables with certain values or dictionary which is key-value data container.

Comment: just use a dictionary

Comment: can you get random different values or do you need specific values associated to each letter? @eggzeyy

Comment: It is home work and he was told not to use dictionary

Comment: @lemon it would need to be those specific values assigned to each letter

Comment: hint: try https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: @Anentropic How is enumerate helpful for this? He doesn't need indexes.

Comment: Why without dictionaries?

Comment: I've recently began learning Python in my spare time and don't want to confuse myself with using dictionaries that I'm not sure what their functions is - not just yet anyways!

Comment: @Barmar _"F is 10, G is 20, H is 30, J is 40 and K is 50"_ so it's like counting through the list starting at 1 and multiplying each index by 10. But I agree, dictionary would be the way to go if it's only a self-imposed restriction

Comment: But the second `F` has to be `10` again, not `40`. @Anentropic

Comment: @Barmar aha missed that ‍♂️

Comment: @eggzeyy just keep in mind, dictionaries play a massive role in Python. They're fundamental to the language. You should try to dive right in and learn about them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```py
letters = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
print(letters)
numbers = [(ord(letter) - ord("A") + 1) * 10 for letter in letters]
print(numbers)
```

That starts at A = 10 to Z = 260

Comment: But op says F= 10

Comment: @TechGeek OP provided an example. And they can customize as much as they wish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and clear way, you need to store your letters to numbers mappings in a dictionary, and then given any list of letters, you can easily convert to the numbers they are mapped to.

```
letter_dict = {'F':10,'G':20,'H':30,'J':40,'K':50} 
letter_lst = ['F','J','H','K','G']

number_lst = [letter_dict[letter] for letter in letter_lst]
print(number_lst)
```

Output:

```
[10, 40, 30, 50, 20]
```